# SQL Query To Get Multiple Max Values From Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to pull multiple max values from multiple columns.  Here is some  sample data:

```
DATE | A | B | C

4/4/2011 | 64.4 | 62.1 | 33.3

4/5/2011 | 34.6 | 33.5 | 32.3

4/6/2011 | 33.1 | 49.4 | 32.1

4/7/2011 | 55.2 | 32.8 | 33.5

4/8/2011 | 31.2 | 50.1 | 30.4

4/9/2011 | 31.7 | 31.1 | 30.4
```

I want the top 5 so:

```
4/4/2011 | 64.4

4/4/2011 | 62.1

4/7/2011 | 55.2

4/8/2011 | 50.1

4/6/2011 | 49.4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Date, Val 
FROM (SELECT Date, A as Val FROM T
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Date, B FROM T
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE, C FROM T
) AS x
ORDER BY x.Val DESC
```

Comment: I don't think I do, but it's probably cleaner that way.

Comment: @hatchet - This is not required. The alias gets taken off the first branch of the `UNION`

Comment: right, I stand corrected. I've been in the habit of doing that so long, I thought it was required.

Comment: @Blarn, no, I don't think so.

Comment: For Posterity, my previous comment was in response to a (subsequently deleted) suggestion that it should be ORDER BY x.Date ASC, x.Val DESC.  Just ORDER BY x.Val DESC is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You could use UNPIVOT then order by the column value then take only the top 5.

Like This......

```
CREATE TABLE #Data 
(
    [Date] DATE,
    A  FLOAT,
    B  FLOAT,
    C  FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO 
    #Data
SELECT '4/4/2011' AS Date, '64.4' AS A, '62.1' AS B, '33.3' AS C
UNION SELECT '4/5/2011' AS Date, '34.6' AS A, '33.5' AS B, '32.3' AS C
UNION SELECT '4/6/2011' AS Date, '33.1' AS A, '49.4' AS B, '32.1' AS C
UNION SELECT '4/7/2011' AS Date, '55.2' AS A, '32.8' AS B, '33.5' AS C
UNION SELECT '4/8/2011' AS Date, '31.2' AS A, '50.1' AS B, '30.4' AS C
UNION SELECT '4/9/2011' AS Date, '31.7' AS A, '31.1' AS B, '30.4' AS C

SELECT * FROM #Data

SELECT TOP 5
    [Date],
    [Type],
    [Value]
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        [Date],
        [A],
        [B],
        [C]
    FROM
        #Data 
)pvt
UNPIVOT
(
    [Value] FOR [Type] IN
    ( [A],[B],[C])
)AS unpvt
ORDER BY
    [Value] DESC

DROP TABLE #Data
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you do not tell us is if you want unique results or allow duplicates.

GilM's answer would allow duplicates because he uses UNION ALL.

UNION would return unique results.