# SQL How to select Max 5 values from table?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

In my database I have two tables  and want to select highest 5 values from table but I only get first highest value cannot get more than one value.

Here is my SQL,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=(SELECT id, MAX(num1+num2) FROM table2 limit 5)
```

How can I get first top 5 highest values?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add sample data so we can understand what you need?

Comment: Not sure but I would go for a IN statement instead of your = in your first query. From here it seems that your subquery return more than one value. Anyway I'm not certain your query works since there are 2 field on the returned sub query.

Comment: Beside the replacement with IN, the inner Select should returns only one column (either id or MAX(...)) and have an ORDER BY statement.  I suspect that we don't have enough information about what the OP wants exactly.

Comment: A lot of answers give select statements that will return 5 rows but how do you then assign them to anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query To Get Multiple Max Values From Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610823/sql-query-to-get-multiple-max-values-from-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 7):

This should do it

```
SELECT id, num1 + num2 AS total FROM table1 ORDER BY num1 + num2 DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: then how do you assign them to local variables?

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this.

```
 SELECT top 5 * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id,MAX(num1+num2) FROM table2) ORDER BY id DESC
```

This will help you.

Comment: SQL Server understands `TOP 5` as well. So that's preferable to `LIMIT 5`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IN operator in your query. So, the subquery must return only 1 column (this is need for IN operator working).

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 ORDER BY num1+num2 DESC LIMIT 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` instead

```
select * from  table1 as t1 , 
table2 as t2 
where t1.id = t2.id 
order by t2.id desc limit 5 ;
```

Comment: You didn't join anything..?

Answer (score 1):

You can Select Top 5 Records As

```
Select Top 5 RestaurantID, RestaurantName,Address,ProfileImage from Restaurant_Details order by DisplayRating Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your sql dialect:

MySQL:

```
SELECT id, num1 + num2 FROM table1 ORDER BY num1 + num2 DESC LIMIT 5
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 5 id, num1 + num2 FROM table1 ORDER BY num1 + num2 DESC
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT id, num1 + num2 FROM table1 WHERE ROWNUM <= 5 ORDER BY num1 + num2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IN operator in your query. So, the subquery must return only 1 column

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(num1+num2) FROM table2) ORDER BY id DESC limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that MAX() is an aggregation function, you'll always get only one row in response when you put it in the field list.

You use ORDER BY and LIMIT in the inner query to fetch 5 values at most (table2 could be smaller):

```
SELECT id FROM table2 ORDER BY num1+num2 DESC LIMIT 5
```

Then you pick the other information wrapping that query with an IN (...)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN ( SELECT id, num1+num2 FROM table2 ORDER BY num1+num2 LIMIT 5 )
```